Compare a number array with existing records in Excel or VBA
I have a sheet with 3k+ lines and 15 columns. Each column is filled with a random number from 1 to 25. Very much like lottery results, where each column is a number drawn from the lottery. (from 1-25)
I need to compare whether the sequence on line 1 (for all 3k+ lines) is found in any other line.
Meaning, whether the lottery results appeared twice. The catch is ball 1 can appear in any of the different 15 columns.

Is the an excel formula I can place in the following column? Or a VBA (ideally) code to compare?

With 2 columns.. in R2 enter =TEXTJOIN(",",,C2:Q2) and then in S2 enter =COUNTIF(R:R,E2). Copy down. Anything higher than a 1 has a match.

Forgot to mention, I am stuck to excel 2016 which does not have the "textjoin" formula

Maybe nit-picking, but surely ball 1 can only appear in the first column of data (C) ?

It can appear in other columns, yes

In 2016, instead of =TEXTJOIN, you could manually build the helper column using =C2&","&D2&","&E2&","...

ok, but as mentioned by @Tom Sharpe above, ball 1 might appear in a different column

That shouldn't matter, provided a. the values are sorted identically (which your sample data suggests) and b. you want to match 15 values against 15 values - and not subsets.

If Bola2 (or higher) can contain the value 1, this would suggest your data isn't sorted - you'll need to sort your data first. In which case post a screenshot of more realistic data that tells us what could be present.

How would you like to return the found similar row?

Please, try the next code. It should do the job in some seconds, according to the probability to not have a match in first columns:
Sub MatchFirstRowNumber()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, mtch, boolNo As Boolean
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:O" & lastR)
 arr = rng.rows(1).Value2 'place the first row in an array

 For i = 2 To rng.rows.count
    boolNo = True
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
      mtch = Application.match(arr(1, j), rng.rows(i), 0)
      If IsError(mtch) Then boolNo = False: Exit For
    Next j
    If boolNo Then MsgBox "Row """ & i + 1 & """ contains the same nubmers as the first one!", vbInformation, "A match has been found"
 Next
End Sub

As return it sends a message mentioning the matching row...
The code can be adapted to (also) return the rows with a specific number of matches (14, for instance...).
Or it can record the matching rows and send a message at the end, mentioning them.
Please, send some feedback after testing it.
Edited:
The next version sends a single message enumerating all matches:
Sub MatchFirstRowNumbers()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, arrRow
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, mtch, boolNo As Boolean, strMatches As String
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:O" & lastR)
 arr = rng.rows(1).Value2 'place the first row in an array
 
 strMatches = "The next matching rows have been found:" & vbCrLf
 For i = 2 To rng.rows.count
    boolNo = True
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
      mtch = Application.match(arr(1, j), rng.rows(i), 0)
      If IsError(mtch) Then boolNo = False: Exit For
    Next j
    If boolNo Then strMatches = strMatches & "Row " & i + 1 & vbCrLf
 Next
 If strMatches <> "The next matching rows have been found:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf Then MsgBox strMatches, vbInformation, "All matches"
End Sub

Second Edit:
The next version is even faster. It gets use of the fact that two arrays can be matched directly, so no iteration between the reference array elements:
Sub MatchFirstRowNumbers()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, arrRow
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrMtch, boolNo As Boolean, strMatches As String
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:O" & lastR)
 arr = rng.rows(1).Value2 'place the first row in an array
 
 strMatches = "The next matching rows have been found:" & vbCrLf
 For i = 2 To rng.rows.count
    boolNo = True
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
      arrMtch = Application.IfError(Application.match(arr, rng.rows(i).Value, 0), "X")  'it places "|" for not matching elements
      If Not IsError(Application.match("X", arrMtch, 0)) Then boolNo = False: Exit For 'if "X" exists change boolNo value and exist For
    Next j
    If boolNo Then strMatches = strMatches & "Row " & i + 1 & vbCrLf
 Next
 If strMatches <> "The next matching rows have been found:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf Then MsgBox strMatches, vbInformation, "All matches"
End Sub


I've tested it on my toy data (changing A2:O to A2:C) and it works perfectly.

Quite impressive the answer from @FaneDuru, worked well, I edited the line as suggested by Tom Sharpe , my data really starts on column C and ends on column Q...now, if it is not to ask too much, how would I proceed to record the matches in another sheet for example? This is not really needed, just so I learn a bit :)

@ROCA In order to work on another sheet it is enough to correctly set ws. Instead of  Set ws = ActiveSheet you should use Set ws = Worksheets("Your sheet name"). Supposing that the respective sheet is in the active workbook. Otherwise, you should qualify it completely. I mean, something as Set ws = Workbooks("The Workbook name").Worksheets("Your sheet name")... And about the rage to be processed, I should mention that the code as it is works on a range starting with A:A column...

Thanks @FaneDuru, I meant to record the matches, the same ones that show up in the dialogue box when it finds a match. I am changing things a bit, for smaller column ranges, it finds several matches, I wanted to make a note of all matches...

@ROCA Not sure I understand what you mean... Would you like the code to send only a single message, enumerating all matching rows? If not, please better describe what you need.

Yes, Got that you started in column A, I was able to edit that, no prob.... thanks again

@ROCA Anyhow, I will edit my answer and place another adapted version to sent only one message. It looks more convenient if more matches will be found, I think. It is easy, no more than 2 to three minutes...

@ROCA Did it. Please, test the code after Edited:... Of course, the same mention related to the range to be processed start (A:A, in my code...).

@ROCA I found a better solution and posted after Second Edit. The first version is fast enough, anyhow, but this one skip iteration between the reference array elements. VBA is able to directly match two arrays and places the error number for the not matching elements.

Just a toy example, but you could try something like this assuming that each row is in ascending order:
=SUM(--(MMULT(ABS(A2:C2-A$2:C$5),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A$2:C$5))^0)=0))

Example with no matches

If the answer is more than 1, there is a duplicate.
In Excel 2016, you might need to array-enter it or use Sumproduct.
Here's an example with a match


You need to lock down those A2:C4's or they'll drift..

There may be a more serious issue, as (I think) 1,2,5 would match with 1,3,4

I think this will fix it.

Is it me, or does that only work with square tables? (3x3, 4x4 etc)

Yup, my bad (it's a long time since I've used mmult like this to be fair) - edit coming up.

Nice! Pure witchcraft, but nice.

Thanks for the fun challenge! Though you have accepted an answer, I wanted to see a way to do it without VBA and with Excel 2016:

Add a helper column with sorted and joined text, unfortunately needs to be filled-down for all the rows
=CONCAT(TEXT(SMALL(C2:Q2, COLUMN(C2:Q2) - COLUMN($C$2) + 1), "00"))
Another column to find duplicates, again fill-down
=COUNTIF($S$2:$S$11, S2) > 1
Use conditional formatting to highlight the duplicate rows (not sure whether this works in Excel 2016 - I don't have it to test); with first cell in the first row selected, enter the first cell from the step above with fixed column reference and relative row reference.
=$T2



Designate Row Containing the Same Integers

For each row, this will populate the R column with a comma-separated list (at least two numbers) of each row index (row of the range) containing the same 15 numbers. The resulting cell becomes empty when no 'matching' row is found,

Unfortunately, the Count/Match combo performs very slow on such a large number of comparisons. It took nearly 4 minutes to complete the task for 3k rows to find the only set of two 'matching' rows.

The sample data was generated using the slow but relatively easy to come up with MS365 formula:
=DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(3000),LAMBDA(rr,r,
    VSTACK(rr,TAKE(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(,25),RANDARRAY(,25)),,15)))),1)

copied and pasted as values. It can be replicated with a fast VBA macro (e.g. search for shuffle array).



Sub TestMatch()
    
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    
    Const COLS_COUNT As Long = 15
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const FIRST_COLUMN As Long = 3
    Const COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 1
    Const DELIMITER As String = ", "
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = rg.Resize(rCount, COLS_COUNT).Offset(FIRST_ROW - 1, FIRST_COLUMN - 1)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To rCount
        dict(i) = Empty
    Next i
    
    Dim srrg As Range, drrg As Range, Count As Long, j As Long
    
    With Application
        For i = 1 To rCount - 1
            If dict.Exists(i) Then
                For j = i + 1 To rCount
                    If dict.Exists(j) Then
                        Count = .Count(.Match(srg.Rows(i), srg.Rows(j), 0))
                        If Count = COLS_COUNT Then
                            If IsEmpty(dict(i)) Then
                                Set dict(i) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                            End If
                            dict(i)(j) = Empty
                            dict.Remove j
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End With
                    
    If dict.Count = rCount Then Exit Sub ' no duplicate rows found
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t
    
    Dim Data() As String: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim oKey As Variant, iKey As Variant, rStr As String
    
    For Each oKey In dict.Keys
        If Not IsEmpty(dict(oKey)) Then
            rStr = oKey
            rStr = rStr & DELIMITER & Join(dict(oKey).Keys, DELIMITER)
            Data(oKey, 1) = rStr
            For Each iKey In dict(oKey).Keys
                Data(iKey, 1) = rStr
            Next iKey
        End If
    Next oKey
        
    Dim drg As Range:
    Set drg = srg.Columns(COLS_COUNT).Offset(, COLUMN_OFFSET)
    drg.Value = Data
        
    Debug.Print Timer - t
        
End Sub

